# How do I get the class from a static method of a subclass?

Tags: java

```
/**
 * this is my class, yadayada. Needs to be subclassed to be useful.
 */
public abstract class MyClass {
  ...
  public static void myMethod() {
    // What is the name of the subclass that's using this?
    System.out.println("Called from class " + this.getClass().class.getName());
    // Doesn't work because there's no "this" in a static method.
  }
}
```

Edit: this is what I want to happen:

```
public class FooClass extends MyClass {
  ...
}

FooClass.myMethod();   // I would like this to print "Called from class FooClass"
```

I'm all out of ideas.

Edit: And for those who wonder why I'm doing it this way, it's actually an Android question of sorts.

Android defines a class called BroadcastReceiver.  You subclass this and register your subclass with the system. When an appropriate broadcast is sent, the system creates an instance of your subclass and calls one of its methods.

I want to create my own BroadcastReceiver subclass that contains a static method for registering itself.  But I also want it to be subclassable.  It sort of looks like this:

```
/**
 * My special-purpose BroadcastReceiver.  Subclass this to use it.
 */
public class MyClass extends BroadcastReceiver {
  public static scheduleAnAlarm(long when) {
    // do some class-specific stuff
    AlarmManager.scheduleBroadcast(MyClass.class, when);
  }

  public void onBroadcast() {
    System.out.println("You should subclass MyClass for it to be useful");
  }
}
```

My problem is that I want to register the subclass to be instantiated, not MyClass.

Comment: For all that answer `MyClass.class`, He is trying to get the `class` of the unspecified subclass. As I point out in my answer, not possible from a static method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't. That is you cannot get the `class` of a subclass from a `static` method.

When Java invokes a `static` method on a class (even one that is `abstract`) no subclass is required therefore none is loaded by the class loader. Therefore there is not necessarily any subclass to get. Even if there was, there could be multiple subclasses so how could Java decide which one you want?

Edit, even with your edit you can't get the subclass. There is a trick you can use with exceptions to get the calling class. You can throw / catch an exception and then walk down the stack trace one level to get the calling method / class. Not recommended!

Comment: See my edit above.  I create a subclass, and call the method from that.  But yeah, I could totally believe that class methods are bound hard to the class in which they're defined.

Comment: Yeah, I was afraid of that.  I was thinking of using reflection somehow, but when you start thinking along those lines, it's time to start thinking about your overall design.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want the class name, then something like below may work:

```
 System.out.println("Called from class " + MyClass.class.getName());
```

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm doing now, but if MyClass gets subclassed, I want this method to return the subclass, not the class in which it's defined.

Comment: He is trying to get the `class` of the unspecified subclass.

Comment: I think fundamentally there are somethings going wrong here, 1) static is specific to CLASS not instance, then it doesn't make sense to write this method as static to get subclass behaviour. May be you need to re-think about the design?

Answer (score 0):

`this` will not work in static context the class instance which you can access there is `MyClass.class`

Answer (score 0):

How about MyClass.class.getName()?

Answer (score -1):

```
public class Foo extends MyClass{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        myMethod();
    }
}
```

and

```
public abstract class MyClass{

    public static void myMethod() {

        System.out.println("Called from class " + MyClass.class.getName());

    }
}
```

Comment: I downvoted this because it is backwards.  The question wants to know the name of Foo at runtime, not the name of MyClass.